# Publishing NPM module to github packages registry from Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-package-registry

My YML so far, kept adding bits based on other stackoverflow threads + docs:

```
name: Node install, build and test

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Create NPMRC
        run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
      - name: Publish to Github Packages
        run: |
          npm config set _auth $NODE_AUTH_TOKEN
          npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

In my package.json I have:

```
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/"
  },
```

And with the above config I keep getting

```
E400 Bad Request
Your request could not be authenticated by the Github Pacakges service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing the wrong content to the ~/.npmrc file.

It should be `//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` but you are doing `//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}`

Comment: I was trying to run `npm publish` with different node env variables, but never worked. Your solution did the job. thanks!